When given a wide passage such as the left-hand part in bars 20-21 - should my fingering seek to avoid the thumb on black keys?
Backstory

Self teaching myself the piano
No warmup routine as of yet
Asked if I could just use the pieces I am working on for warmup
Was told yes; just choose the most difficult passage and focus on that.


So for the left hand, I decided to go with that passage which has such a huge range in fairly rapid succession.
The trouble is how should I tackle the B♭'s? No fingering drills ( All I have done is go through the 15 major scales ) I have done up until this point ever place a thumb on a black key, and so I am wondering if I should avoid doing that here too?
The first three notes though cover an octave, which could be
B♭1 - Pinky
F2  - Index
B♭2 - Thumb

Question:
When constructing my fingering for wide passages, should I minimize the thumbs falling upon black keys? Or should I perhaps learn to get used to it?
Are there any schools of thought I can defer to when it comes to wide fingering techniques? Or should I just go by intuition?
Thanks~

"just choose the most difficult passage and focus on that": that's not a warmup.  A warmup would typically focus on the easier passages and then, as you get more warmed up, move on to more difficult passages.  Using the most difficult passage as a warmup is like running a marathon as a warmup -- it is actually just dispensing with the warmup altogether.

How do you play/finger the C major arpeggio two bars later? That one might not be too different from the B-flat one.

15 Major scales?

Who did you "ask if you could just use the pieces you are working on for warmup"?

TLDR: For "wide fingering techniques", if it involves arpeggios, use standard fingering as much as possible, with the thumb either on F or on D for a B-flat major arpeggio.  For your bars 20-21 I recommend using your thumb consistently on D, but since your pinky is on A in the previous bar and the first D is missing, I would start with 5-3.  Thus we have: 5-3-2-1-4-2 | 1-2-4-1-2-3.
See the rest of the answer below for a more general guide on how to choose fingering.

Generally, using the thumb on black keys should be avoided for stability reason.  In your case, you'll be doing arpeggios but using thumb on B-flat major arpeggio is not stable, reflected by many standard fingerings for it that studiously avoid placing the thumb on B-flat.
However, let's say you're playing a rapid passage involving octaves like measure 32 of Chopin's "Military Polonaise" Op. 40 No. 1, then it's perfectly fine to use the thumb on black keys because it's the most STABLE fingering for that passage (pianists usually use both the LH and RH thumbs for all black keys in that octave passage with alternating ring & little fingers for the other notes).  Fingering suggested by the 1881 Schirmer edition:

Here's a general rule.  When playing any complex passage in piano music,

The #1 consideration is that the fingering should assist you to make beautiful phrases by avoiding awkward finger-change, finger-going-under, or unstable finger in the most important notes.  Thus, in the case of arpeggios, the sound of the notes should be well connected.

Use the fingering for scales and arpeggios that you are already used to (why reinvent the wheel?)  If you have not done so, I highly recommend practicing scales and arpeggios using standard fingering (designed for ease and stability), for example from James Francis Cooke's Mastering the Scales and Arpeggios (1913) (thanks, @MichaelCurtis):

B-flat Major arpeggio


C Major arpeggio


G Minor arpeggio





Applying the above 2 principles, the fingering should be straightforward:

For the B-flat arpeggio in measures 20-21 I would use: 3-1-3-2-1-3 | 2-3-1-2-3-1 (thumb on F) which connects well with the

C major arpeggio in measures 22-23 where I would use 5-2-1-4-2-1 | 2-1-2-4-1-2 which nicely prepares you for the

G minor arpeggio in measure 24 : 5-2-1-4-2-1 and finally

Standard C major fingering again in measure 25 : 5-2-1-2-1-2.


(the bold fingering was an exception since it is a non-root turning note before going down again).
But if we prioritize principle #1, an alternate fingering for measures 20-21 would be: 5-3-2-1-4-2 | 1-2-4-1-2-3 (thumb on D) which feels very stable to me and connects more smoothly to the C arpeggio on measure 22.  I recommend this one (similar to @Aaron's).

There are times when having your thumb on a black key makes it harder to reach certain white keys around it. But there definitely isn't any rule like "never play a black key with your thumb," and in my experience it's irrelevant far more often than it comes up. There's no reason I can see to avoid it in the measure you highlighted.
Don't overanalyze fingerings. You'll know if it feels wrong or impossible.

TL;DR: The recommended detail is to use the thumb on F3 (the 5th note in the Bb arpeggio).

Your fingering scheme for the beginning of the passage is a good one.

B♭1 - Pinky
F2  - Index
B♭2 - thumb

One school of thought — the one I adhere to — is to organize fingering in terms of groups of notes that can be played in one hand position without twisting and avoiding stretching where possible.
The portion of this passage that is more awkward is what comes just after the lowest octave. The obvious fingering would be 4-2-1, but that means crossing over from 1 on Bb3 to 2 on D4. It also could make the downward arpeggio awkward.
I would consider 5-1-5 (2, 3, or 4)-1-2-1 (see illustration, below). If this works for you, it puts your hand in a better position for the downward arpeggio, starting with 1 of D4.
Another option — not necessarily a good one, but worth mentioning — would be to play the D4 with your right hand. In this case, you'd use the pedal to hold the right-hand A, jump down to play the left hand's D, and then back up to play the F-A dyad. I'd say its not a great solution here, but worth noting because it may be handy in the future for some other passage.
One way or another, this is just an awkward arpeggio to deal with, so the strategy is to find the least awkward fingering.
Illustration: Suggested fingering


You wrote "no drills." I'm not sure if you mean you haven't done a basic piano method for scales and arpeggios. If not, you should. Something like this: https://imslp.org/wiki/Mastering_the_Scales_and_Arpeggios_(Cooke%2C_James_Francis). That will take you a long way to understand piano fingering.
B♭1 - Pinky
F2  - Index
B♭2 - thumb

For the left hand yes. You should use finger numbering, which in this case will be LH 5 2 1 to play B♭1 F2 B♭2.

...should I minimize the thumbs falling upon black keys? Or should I perhaps learn to get used to it?

Avoiding the thumb on black keys is more of an issue for playing scales. When playing chords you need to freely use the thumb on black keys.
